# Any reason why the mouse cursor keeps shown even after leaving out the pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

When running the application and getting inside the pictureBoxImageToCrop the mouse cursor do get hidden and isRealTimeCropping is true.

then when leaving out the pictureBoxImageToCrop it's showing the mouse cursor again but then when entering again it keep showing the mouse cursor instead hide it again.

if I comment not to use the line:

```
Cursor.Show();
```

in the leave event it will work fine but I want to see the mouse cursor when leaving the pictureBox. I can't figure out why it happens.

I used a breakpoint and it's getting also on the other times to the Hide line but it's not hiding it.

```
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drawCircle = false;
    drawRectangle = false;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    Cursor.Show();
    pictureBoxImageToCrop.Invalidate();
}
```

and

```
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
        pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = null;
    }

    if (radioButtonCircular.Checked)
    {
        drawRectangle = false;
        drawCircle = true;
    }
    else if (radioButtonRectangular.Checked)
    {
        drawRectangle = true;
        drawCircle = false;
    }

    pictureBoxImageToCrop.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Cursor.Hide()` conditionally but `Cursor.Show()` unconditionally.
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide), these calls must however be balanced.

If it ever happens that `isRealTimeCropping` is false when entering, you have more `Show()` than `Hide()` Calls.

If `isRealTimeCropping` cannot change between the Enter and Leave event, just make the call to `Cursor.Show()` also conditional on `isRealTimeCropping`. If this is not guaranteed, add another variable to keep track of the fact whether or not you called `Cursor.Hide()`.